# How can i combine two selects from two tables?

Tags: php, mysql

This is my DB schema:

```
CREATE TABLE `members` (
  `m_id` int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `m_name` varchar(355),
  `m_email` varchar(20) UNIQUE,
  PRIMARY KEY (`m_id`)
);

CREATE TABLE `schools` (
  `s_id` int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `s_name` varchar(355)
);

CREATE TABLE `schools_members` (
  `sm_id` int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `sm_school_id` int NOT NULL,
  `sm_member_id` int NOT NULL,
FOREIGN KEY (sm_school_id) REFERENCES schools(s_id),
FOREIGN KEY (sm_member_id) REFERENCES members(m_id)
);
```

I need to display all members for a selected school by a given school id (`$schoolId`). So i assume that the query will touch on `schools_members` and `members`.

I believe the logic is: select all the `sm_member_id` where `sm_school_id` = `$schoolId` from table `schools_members` and then SELECT `m_name` and
`m_email` for each `m_id` (member id) from table `members` that is IN the last query result.

**This is not required**, but now im curious if i want to join to this result the `s_name` (school name) from table `schools` so that each member displays the name of school also?

Comment: yes - this is a JOIN

Comment: @Randy could you please help me with the query? Im not confrotable with joins

Comment: E.g. `SELECT m.m_id, m.m_name, m.m_email FROM members m INNER JOIN schools_members sm ON sm.sm_member_id = m.m_id WHERE sm.sm_school_id = ?`

Comment: @Dharman i've removed now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just use a join between schools_members and members

```
select m.m_name, m.m_email
from schools_members sm 
inner join members m ON m.m_id = sm.sm_member_id 
where sm.sm_school_id =  Your_value
```

and for school name

```
select m.m_name, m.m_email, s.s_name
from schools_members sm 
inner join members m ON m.m_id = sm.sm_member_id 
inner join schools s on s.s_id = sm.sm_school_id
where sm.sm_school_id =  Your_value
```

Comment: m.m_name, m.m_e_email should be from table members and you have a typo on 'membres' is members. Please fix in order for me to accept your answer

Comment: ... i have changed  m_email  (instead of m_m_email)  and members instead of membres  ... then  m is the alias  for the members  table  ..  so m.m_name and m.m_email are from table members ..  .. if there is others let me know  ..

Comment: You right, the first select was confusing me but now i see... Both are working, answer accepted